# Java external library in terminal error

Tags: java, terminal, package, classpath, external

In terminal, I get the follow error after I compile my program:

WriteExcel.java:7: error: package jxl does not exist

I compiled the program by typing:

```
    javac -cp /Desktop/folder/src/jxl.jar WriteExcel.java
```

Basically, how do I get the compiler to recognize the external library?

Comment: What is at line 7 of the source?

Comment: Is the path correct?  What do you see when you execute `ls /Desktop/folder/src/jxl.jar`?

Comment: hm, i got this: /Desktop/folder/src/jxl.jar: No such file or directory

Comment: Maybe you meant `~/Desktop/folder/src/jxl.jar`?

Comment: oh, right.  it says: line 1: PK: command not found line 2: cqX: command not found bqX: command not found

Comment: So the file is there. Then do `javac -cp ~/Desktop/folder/src/jxl.jar WriteExcel.java`. And you should read a book about linux.

Comment: Okay, it compiled.  Now I get the following error after I do java WriteExcel: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jxl/write/WritableCell
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)

Comment: You also need the jar file while running your program. So add the same -cp option.

Comment: java -cp ~/Desktop/folder/srx/jxl.jar WriteExcel gave me the error: Could not find or load main class WriteExcel.  I'm not sure if that's what you mean by adding the same -cp option.

Comment: JVM doesn't know where your class file is.  Append `:.` after the jar.